# Simplify case-if-else ladder in C# code

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

EDIT: I am more interested in particular programming practice or way of coding to avoid this. But any suggestion is welcome.

I have written this ugly looking code to perform certain tasks:

```
switch(arg[0])
{ 
    case "a"
    {
        foreach(var c in obja)
        {
            if(c.entry == 'a')
            {
                if (Independent_condition_1)
                {
                    // do logging
                    continue;
                }
                if (Independent_condition_2)
                {
                    // do logging
                    continue;
                }
                // Do something if above two conditions are false
            }
            else
            {
                if (Independent_condition_3)
                {
                    // do logging
                    continue;
                }
                if (Independent_condition_4)
                {
                    // do logging
                    continue;
                }
                // do something if above 2 conditions are false.
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case "b"
    {
        // similar if else ladder
    }   
}
```

Problem is the code looks ugly and is very unreadable. I've moved most of the things inside if-else to functions just to simplify the code. What's the alternative of such long nested if-else?

Comment: question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a lot of unecessary branches in your code. I would combine and negate them. This will make the code a bit more readable.

```
switch(arg[0])
{ 
 case "a"
 {
  foreach(var c in obja)
  {
     if(c.entry == 'a')
     {
        if(!(Independent_condition_1 || Independent_condition_2))
        {
          // Do something
        }
      }
     else
      {
       if(!(Independent_condition_3 || Independent_condition_4)
        {
         // do something
        }
       }
     break;
      }
 case "b"
  {
  //similar if else ladder
  }   
}
```

Next I would break it down into different methods. By naming the methods something sensible that fits with your domain wyou will make the code much more readable.It also means when you are making a change you only have to think about the small section your are working on, not the whole complicated method.

```
switch(arg[0])
{ 
 case "a"
 {
  foreach(var c in obja)
  {
     newMethod(c);
     break;
      }
 case "b"
  {
  //similar if else ladder
  }   
}

void newMethod(str c) {
  if(c.entry == 'a')
     {
        if(!(Independent_condition_1 || Independent_condition_2))
        {
          // Do something
        }
      }
     else
      {
       if(!(Independent_condition_3 || Independent_condition_4)
        {
         // do something
        }
       }
}
```

You could then continue to break this down into smaller well named methods until it is more easily understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method which does the if/else stuff and call that inside the switch, you wont be duplicating code and you wont have a massive switch block:

```
switch(arg[0])
{
     case "a":
        DoStuff('a');
        break;
     case "b":
        DoStuff('b');
        break;
     default:
        break;
}

private void DoStuff(char c)
{
   foreach(var c in obja)
   {
       if(c.entry == c)
       {
           if (Independent_condition_1)
           {
               // do logging
               continue;
           }
           if (Independent_condition_2)
           {
                // do logging
                continue;
           }
              // Do something if above two conditions are false
        }
        else
        {
            if (Independent_condition_3)
            {
                // do logging
                continue;
            }
            if (Independent_condition_4)
            {
                // do logging
                continue;
            }
            // do something if above 2 conditions are false.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create lots private methods which make decisions or deal with single cases, or encapsulate the logic for individual cases in separate classes. The latter makes it easier to test, while the former just prevents your code getting unwieldy.

I tend to aim for a cyclomatic complexity of no more than 5 within a single method (if I can help it...) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182212.aspx

An example of your code using private methods:

```
 private void method(string[] arg)
    {
        switch (arg[0])
        {
            case "a":
                HandleCaseA();
                break;

            case "b":
                HandleCaseB();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("arg");
        }
    }



    private void HandleCaseA()
    {
        foreach (var c in obja)
        {
            if (c.entry == 'a')
                HandleSubCaseA();
            else if (!(Independent_condition_3 || Independent_condition_4)
            HandleSubCaseAWithConditions3And4();

        }           
    }

    private void HandleSubCaseA()
    {
        if (!(Independent_condition_1 || Independent_condition_2))
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleCaseB ()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    private void HandleSubCaseAWithConditions3And4()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk up conditions and handling in methods. If the conditions are independent as you write, there is no switch so you'll have to divide up the work in more readable (or less unreadable) blocks, like so:

```
if (c.entry == 'a')
{
     ProcessEntryA(c);
} else ...
     // etc
}
```